# solving system of equations(nonlinear)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve the following system of equations:

$$\frac{kq^2}{d}=mg(L-L\cos(t))+\frac{kq^2}{r}$$
$$\sin(t)=\frac{x}{L}$$
$$r^2=(L-L\cos(t))^2+(x+d)^2$$

The parameters are: $k,L,d,q,m,g$

The variables: $x,r,t$

all parameters and variables $> 0$

I tried using wolfram but it gave me weird answers.

Comment: If I'm looking at this right, you're trying to balance a charge in a gravitational field? Also, note that all of the parameters in here---$m$,$g$, etc---are likely to be clouding the algebra. It may help to define a few new variables (like $x/L$, for example) which don't require you to have to worry about units. (Though that does make it harder to check your answer via dimensional analysis.)

Comment: I tried u = x / L but it dosen't solve it.

Comment: Well, it won't solve it, it'll just make it easier to solve. (I might add: Despite this being a math question, it wouldn't be a bad idea to include a picture of your geometry just to make things accessible to your readers here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s = \sin(t)$ and $c = \cos(t)$, with the equation $s^2 + c^2 = 1$.
Then you have a system of equations in rational functions.
One solution is $x=0,r=d,s=0,c=1$.  The others depend on solving a quintic equation.  If $r$ is a solution of
$$ {d}^{2}{g}^{2}{m}^{2}{z}^{5}+{d}^{3}{g}^{2}{m}^{2}{z}^{4}+ \left( -{d}
^{4}{g}^{2}{m}^{2}-4\,Ldgkm{q}^{2} \right) {z}^{3}-{d}^{5}{g}^{2}{m}^{
2}{z}^{2}+ \left( -4\,L{d}^{3}gkm{q}^{2}+4\,{L}^{2}{k}^{2}{q}^{4}+4\,{
d}^{2}{k}^{2}{q}^{4} \right) z-4\,{L}^{2}d{k}^{2}{q}^{4}-4\,{d}^{3}{k}
^{2}{q}^{4}
=0$$
then you have

$$\eqalign{c&=1+{\frac {k{q}^{2}}{gmLr}}-{\frac {k{q}^{2}}{mgLd}}\cr s&=-\dfrac12
\,{\frac {d}{L}}+\dfrac12\,{\frac {{r}^{2}}{Ld}}+{\frac {k{q}^{2}}{mgdr}}-{
\frac {k{q}^{2}}{gm{d}^{2}}}\cr x&=-\dfrac{d}{2}+\dfrac12\,{\frac {{r}^{2}}{d}}+{\frac {
Lk{q}^{2}}{mgdr}}-{\frac {Lk{q}^{2}}{gm{d}^{2}}}\cr}$$